# Global Object in ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

```
private var _product:Product;

        [Bindable]
        public function get product():Product
        {
            return _product;
        }

        public function set product(p:Product):void
        {
            _product = p;
            tn.selectedIndex = 0;
        }

<mx:Label text="{product.name}" fontSize="11" fontWeight="bold"/>
```

How are they getting the product.name value which is inside product class.

```
package samples.flexstore
{

[Bindable]
public class Product
{

    public var productId:int;
    public var name:String;
    public var description:String;
    public var price:Number;
    public var image:String;
    public var series:String;
    public var triband:Boolean;
    public var camera:Boolean;
    public var video:Boolean;
    public var highlight1:String;
    public var highlight2:String;
    public var qty:int;

    public function Product()
    {

    }

    public function fill(obj:Object):void
    {
        for (var i:String in obj)
        {
            this[i] = obj[i];
        }
    }

    [Bindable(event="propertyChange")]
    public function get featureString():String
    {
        var str:String = "";
        if (triband)
            str += "Tri-band ";

        if (camera)
            str += "Camera ";

        if (video)
            str += "Video";

        return str;
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"{product.name}" , the product refers to the getter method!

That's the trick of Flex/ActionScript 3's getter and setter methods
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=ascomponents_147_08.html

Answer (score 0):

"name" is a public var on the Product class. By definition, "name" will be accessible to any other class. That's what "public" means.

Answer (score 0):

*_product* is a private instance of the *Product* class. They are supplying the *set product* method with a *Product* value, which sets the *_product* private variable to an instance of the Product class.

The [bracket notation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/using_data_binding/#section1) in the *text="{product.name}"* portion of the above code is shorthand notation for binding the contained variable, in this case the *name* property of the *product* instance, to the component property (*text*). When the *set product* method is supplied a *Product* instance, Flex fires events internally that update the components that have that property bound.

[Defining Data Models - Flex Quickstarts](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/defining_data_models/)